# MySQL JOIN tables with COUNT values

Tags: mysql, database, join, count

I have the following tables in my database.I only listed the important columns which can be used for joining.

[image]

I need to get the following output
[image]

Currently I'm using two seperate queries for each **COUNT** value

For assigned licenses

```
select
    products.id,products.name,COUNT(assigned_licenses.id)
from
    deployment_users
inner join
    assigned_licenses 
on
    deployment_users.id = assigned_licenses.deployment_user_id
inner join
    products
on
    assigned_licenses.id = products.id
and
    deployment_users.customer_id = 10
group by
    assigned_licenses.id
;
```

For total licenses

```
select
    products.id,products.name,COUNT(total_licenses.id)
from
    customers
inner join
    total_licenses
on
    customers.iccode = licenses.iccode
inner join
    products
on
    total_licenses.id = products.id
and
    customers.id = 10
group by
    total_licenses.id
;
```

Since there are more than a 1,000 products that need to be listed,I want to combine them into a single query.How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your specification leaves some room for interpretation (e.g. can a user have assigned licenses without total licenses? if yes my query will fail.) but I would go with this.

```
SELECT
    products.id,
    products.name,
    Count(Distinct total_licenses.id) As CountTotalLicenses,
    Count(Distinct assigned_liceses.deployment_users_id) As CountAssignedLicenses
FROM products
    LEFT JOIN total_licenses ON total_licenses.products_id = products.id
    LEFT JOIN customers ON customers.iccode = total_licenses.customers_iccode
    LEFT JOIN assigned_licenses ON assigned_liceses.total_licenses_id = total_licenses.id
WHERE
    customers.id = 10
GROUP BY
    products.id,
    products.name
```

For the future it would be awesome if you could paste code as code and not as an image. People cannot simple copy paste snippets of your code and have to type everything again...

Comment: Cool. You Didn't use `deployment_users` at all.Can you explain the thinking behind this query?

Comment: Hmmm the thingking hmmm :)

Comment: If you mean "how does it work", the trick is behind those "Count(Distinct ...)" expressions with the group by. if you have 5 rows with a column X with the values (5, 2, 4, 2, 1) then it will return 4. For values (3, 3, 5, 5) it will return 2. So it will check how many "unique" occurences of that value exist and count those. Does this help you to understand it?

Comment: Honestly,no. Still trying to wrap my head around it.

Comment: Try to understand this first https://pastebin.com/3PEvxYbM Its the query above without the the grouping. And then read my answer above again. Maybe that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try joining Both of your query

```
SELECT * FROM (
   (First Query) as assigned_licn 
   INNER JOIN 
   (Second Query) as total_licn
   USING (id)
);
```